# Local Storage is not working with Intel XDK

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I am running an Ionic app using AngularJS with Intel XDK. But while the app is running, local Storage is not working. Whats the problem. Does Intel XDK support local Storage?

Comment: Intel XDK does support LocalStorage. In Emulator if you launch Debugger and open Resources tab, you can see in left menu LocalStorage among some other storages.